# Retain URLs using nltk Tokenizing

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I use nltk to tokenize words. But I want to retain the urls in the sentences. 
For example:

Input

```
It’s word1 word2 https://www.google.com. Word3 word4 (word5). Word6 word7 http://visjs.org/#gallery word8. Word9 word10 (https://www.baidu.com). Word11-word12 word13 word14 http://visjs.org/#gallery.
```

Desired output:

```
It s word1 word2 https://www.google.com Word3 word4 word5 Word6 word7 word8 Word9 word10 https://www.baidu.com Word11 word12 word13 word14 http://visjs.org/#gallery
```

I use  `tokens=WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(Input)`, but it can not remove the delimiters and punctuations. Anyone can provide a solution?

Comment: are you using 2.7 or 3.5 or something else? I get the right output in 3.5.1 with the most recent nltk package. it seems to treat urls as a single token

Comment: @jalomas7 are you talking about the python version? nltk latest stable on github is 3.2.5 - with that nltk and python 3.5, url's are split by `word_tokenize()`

Answer (score 1):

nltk has a tokeniser `nltk.tokenize.casual_tokenize` that will do what you want, though it doesn't do the fancy things `word_tokenize` does with contractions and the like.

Casual docs are [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/casual.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> text = "It’s word1 word2 https://www.google.com. Word3 word4 (word5). Word6 word7 http://visjs.org/#gallery word8. Word9 word10 (https://www.baidu.com). Word11-word12 word13 word14 http://visjs.org/#gallery."
>>> _text = " ".join([w.strip('.,()') for w in text.split()])
>>> print _text.replace("’s", " 's")
It 's word1 word2 https://www.google.com Word3 word4 word5 Word6 word7 http://visjs.org/#gallery word8 Word9 word10 https://www.baidu.com Word11-word12 word13 word14 http://visjs.org/#gallery
```

or

```
>>> text = "It’s word1 word2 https://www.google.com. Word3 word4 (word5). Word6 word7 http://visjs.org/#gallery word8. Word9 word10 (https://www.baidu.com). Word11-word12 word13 word14 http://visjs.org/#gallery."
>>> _text = text.replace("’s", " 's")
>>> _text = " ".join([w.strip(".,()'") for w in _text.split()])
>>> print _text
It s word1 word2 https://www.google.com Word3 word4 word5 Word6 word7 http://visjs.org/#gallery word8 Word9 word10 https://www.baidu.com Word11-word12 word13 word14 http://visjs.org/#gallery
```